# How to calculate the limit of this sequence which incorporates tan?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was revising for my pre-calculus exam, which is in two weeks time, and I started proving some sequence related theorems. I got interested in limits and I started deepening the concept. I got to a halt point when I wanted to prove that the limit of the sequence $$a_n= \frac{2n}{\tan(\pi/2 - \pi/n)} $$ $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n> 3 $$ is equal to $2\pi$ for $n \to \infty$. Any idea about how the proof should be done?

Comment: Are you familiar with L'hospital's Rule?

Comment: Yes, I am. Is the limit of $\tan(\pi/2 - \pi/n)$ for $n \to \infty$ infinity?

Comment: Well, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \tan(\pi/2-\pi/n) = \tan(\pi/2)$ because $\pi/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: Yes, I reckon that, you are right, cheers! But how do I come at $2\pi$?

Comment: It'll come about from using L'hospital's rule :) I'll post how below if you would like

Comment: Mmh, I would first like to try it myself, but I need to revise trig derivatives and trig rules, I guess, I feel quite ignorant about periodic functions at this point in time. Thank you immensely for your help, in any case!

Comment: you have a great attitude about math :) Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2n}{\tan(\pi/2-\pi/n)}=2n\tan\frac{\pi}{n},$$
and since $\tan(x)=x+o(x^2)$ in a right neighbourhood of zero, the claim follows.

Comment: I understand what you did in order to get the $2n \tan\frac{\pi}{n}$, simple trig rules, but I am sorry to have to say that I have no idea about the meaning of what you have written. Could you please give me a hint about what it represents, at least?

Comment: @E.S.L.: it simply means that in a neighbourhood of the origin $\tan x$ behaves like $x$. You can prove, for instance, that for any $x\in(0,1)$ we have $\tan x > x$ but $\tan x < x e^{x^2/3}$, so the claim follows by squeezing.

Comment: After a bit of ponderation I think I got your point. It is indeed easier to prove the claim by using Taylor...thank you for your time & help, Jack D'Aurizio!